# How to allow users to set up a color theme?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm just curious as to how Twitter allows it's users to choose a color theme. Is this a CSS or jQuery approach? It probably saves the color in the database.

If so, how and what steps are necessary to implement something similar?

**Additional information**:
It seems that the most common answer is to use multiple CSS files and load the one which is selected by the user.

Sorry I should have included right at the beginning that the process includes having the user select a color from a color picker (similar to WordPress themes where they indicate that the theme has unlimited colors). Creating a separate CSS for all of these colors is probably not a good idea.

Comment: you have to create database entry for color according to user or user id ,if user changes color then you have to apply that color on page and update database table .. when user login into account you have to fetch that color according to user's unique id and apply on page

Comment: @KaranAdhikari So how do I do it with CSS? I get the point where you pass the color from a color picker and save it to the database, but we have to remember that I only use 1 CSS file. Do I physically change the value of the colors on the file? Or is there a CSS variable of some sort?

Comment: you can do it with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, so without getting into too much detail I'll try to give you some ideas on how to approach this. Remember there's many ways to do this, so there's no 'one way' set in stone, and mine is just an idea.

You'll need to store the chosen values somewhere, depending on your needs. You can save them in a database, a cookie, the session or even locally, if they don't need to persist.

You should probably save the values in a dictionary (an associative array), which holds a key and a value. The key would be the identifier of the element, and the value would be the color. That way, you can request the value based on the identifier of the element you're applying the value to.

Applying the color can also be done in a few ways. I would suggest jQuery. That way, you won't have to apply a style tag to each element holding the color definition. You can simply use jQuery.css(). (take a look at http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 2):

I have to say, I dont really know twitter as Im not using it. From my understanding you'r just looking for a method to give the user the chance to pick a theme for a webpage right?

Lets say we got a page called "config.php" which gets included on every webpage (brings often used functions etc.). On top of this config.php you declared your .css-file which will be included at the beginning. Why dont you just place different css-files for building up different designs?

For example:
**Config.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['design'])){
    switch($_SESSION['design']){
        case 0: $design = 'included/main_theme.css';
        case 1: $design = 'included/black_theme.css';
        case 2: $design = 'included/red_theme.css';
        case 3: $design = 'included/blue_theme.css';
    }
}
else{
    $design = 'included/main_theme.css';
}

echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC//...">//
      <link href="'.$design.'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
?>
```

Now you just need to setup a page where the user can choose his favourite design. Submit a form to the page itself, store the picked design into the session of the user and reload the page again. You'r done!

You could also store this state in a database (what would be better I guess).
With this method you could for sure also just set a single style like background-color.

**The rest of the website:**
Just go ahead and include config.php into every page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, but simple JS is enough. Simply create 2 or more stylesheets and then allow your users to change the styles like this:

```
<form>
<input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('blue');return false;" name="theme" value="Blue Theme" id="blue">
<input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('pink');return false;" name="theme" value="Pink Theme" id="pink">
</form>
```

from [How to Use JavaScript to Change a Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) Dynamically](http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml) . Of course it will depend on your approach, it's way easier if you use a CMS, it also depends on whether you want your users to change themes "on the fly" or to have something selected in an admin area or whatever option you need